# Kettle job launched with a scheduler doesn't have permits on folders (Linux)

Tags: linux, permissions, pentaho, chmod, kettle

i have a problem with a Kettle job, which is also a problem about linux.
I have a Job that create a few folders, deletes other folders and create some files and put them in these folders. I won't describe exactly what the job does because it's not the point. Before starting describing my problem i want to say that this job works perfectly, i mean that if i launch this job from spoon or from my ubuntu (14.04) terminal, with kitchen obviously, everything works just fine. The problem is that i started using a scheduler (a software wrote in java from a person that i know) to launch many job periodically. The strange fact is that when this scheduler launch the job, and it tries to create folders and files, it doesn't have the permits to do that. The developer ensured me that the scheduler launch the job with the same user and group of the main folder in which i write. I mean, if i launch the command `ls -al` from terminal it shows `ubuntu ubuntu` as user/group of the folder and these are the same used by the scheduler. But unfortunately i can't tell you more about it, and i don't really have the chance to manage the scheduler code and modify it, so i havo to solve the problem in another way.

The first thing i tried it's been the change of the permits in the folder in which i create sub-folders and files with my Job. I gave all the permits at the folder and sub folders with the command `sudo chmod 777 -R /media/Folder` (as you can see i work mainly in the /media folder). Now the transformation is able to write the first sub-folder, let say `/media/Folder/First_Folder`, but it still doesn't have permits on the new Folder, i mean it can't create the folder `/media/Folder/First_Folder/Second_Folder` because this new folder (Second_Folder) hasn't inherited the permits from the parent folder (since it has been created later than the chmod command). So i'm looking a way to give the right permits at the folders and files newly created in the parent folder in where i work. Many people suggest to use the command `umask`, but this has to be done with the process which create the folder, and i can't do it. Anybody know another way to fix this problem acting on the folders permits ?

The second solution that i have in mind is changing the source code of the job entries of Pentaho Kettle. I thought that may be i could add some line of code which could change the permits of the folder in where i want to create a new one. I found for example the code of the Create a Folder job entry, and may be i should add something right there. But before i do this i would like to know if somebody has already done anything like this (or similar).
Here's the code:

```
package org.pentaho.di.job.entries.createfolder;

import static org.pentaho.di.job.entry.validator.AbstractFileValidator.putVariableSpace;
import static org.pentaho.di.job.entry.validator.AndValidator.putValidators;
import static org.pentaho.di.job.entry.validator.JobEntryValidatorUtils.andValidator;
import static org.pentaho.di.job.entry.validator.JobEntryValidatorUtils.fileDoesNotExistValidator;
import static org.pentaho.di.job.entry.validator.JobEntryValidatorUtils.notNullValidator;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.commons.vfs.FileObject;
import org.apache.commons.vfs.FileType;
import org.pentaho.di.cluster.SlaveServer;
import org.pentaho.di.core.CheckResultInterface;
import org.pentaho.di.core.Result;
import org.pentaho.di.core.database.DatabaseMeta;
import org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleDatabaseException;
import org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleException;
import org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleXMLException;
import org.pentaho.di.core.variables.VariableSpace;
import org.pentaho.di.core.variables.Variables;
import org.pentaho.di.core.vfs.KettleVFS;
import org.pentaho.di.core.xml.XMLHandler;
import org.pentaho.di.job.JobMeta;
import org.pentaho.di.job.entries.createfile.JobEntryCreateFile;
import org.pentaho.di.job.entry.JobEntryBase;
import org.pentaho.di.job.entry.JobEntryInterface;
import org.pentaho.di.job.entry.validator.ValidatorContext;
import org.pentaho.di.repository.ObjectId;
import org.pentaho.di.repository.Repository;
import org.pentaho.metastore.api.IMetaStore;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;

/**
* This defines a 'create folder' job entry. Its main use would be to create empty folder that can be used to control
* the flow in ETL cycles.
*
* @author Sven/Samatar
* @since 18-10-2007
*
*/
public class JobEntryCreateFolder extends JobEntryBase implements Cloneable, JobEntryInterface {
  private String foldername;
  private boolean failOfFolderExists;

  public JobEntryCreateFolder( String n ) {
    super( n, "" );
    foldername = null;
    failOfFolderExists = true;
  }

  public JobEntryCreateFolder() {
    this( "" );
  }

  public Object clone() {
    JobEntryCreateFolder je = (JobEntryCreateFolder) super.clone();
    return je;
  }

  public String getXML() {
    StringBuffer retval = new StringBuffer( 50 );

    retval.append( super.getXML() );
    retval.append( " " ).append( XMLHandler.addTagValue( "foldername", foldername ) );
    retval.append( " " ).append( XMLHandler.addTagValue( "fail_of_folder_exists", failOfFolderExists ) );

    return retval.toString();
  }

  public void loadXML( Node entrynode, List<DatabaseMeta> databases, List<SlaveServer> slaveServers,
    Repository rep, IMetaStore metaStore ) throws KettleXMLException {
    try {
      super.loadXML( entrynode, databases, slaveServers );
      foldername = XMLHandler.getTagValue( entrynode, "foldername" );
      failOfFolderExists = "Y".equalsIgnoreCase( XMLHandler.getTagValue( entrynode, "fail_of_folder_exists" ) );
    } catch ( KettleXMLException xe ) {
      throw new KettleXMLException( "Unable to load job entry of type 'create folder' from XML node", xe );
    }
  }

  public void loadRep( Repository rep, IMetaStore metaStore, ObjectId id_jobentry, List<DatabaseMeta> databases,
    List<SlaveServer> slaveServers ) throws KettleException {
    try {
      foldername = rep.getJobEntryAttributeString( id_jobentry, "foldername" );
      failOfFolderExists = rep.getJobEntryAttributeBoolean( id_jobentry, "fail_of_folder_exists" );
    } catch ( KettleException dbe ) {
      throw new KettleException(
        "Unable to load job entry of type 'create Folder' from the repository for id_jobentry=" + id_jobentry,
        dbe );
    }
  }

  public void saveRep( Repository rep, IMetaStore metaStore, ObjectId id_job ) throws KettleException {
    try {
      rep.saveJobEntryAttribute( id_job, getObjectId(), "foldername", foldername );
      rep.saveJobEntryAttribute( id_job, getObjectId(), "fail_of_folder_exists", failOfFolderExists );
    } catch ( KettleDatabaseException dbe ) {
      throw new KettleException( "Unable to save job entry of type 'create Folder' to the repository for id_job="
        + id_job, dbe );
    }
  }

  public void setFoldername( String foldername ) {
    this.foldername = foldername;
  }

  public String getFoldername() {
    return foldername;
  }

  public String getRealFoldername() {
    return environmentSubstitute( getFoldername() );
  }

  public Result execute( Result previousResult, int nr ) {
    Result result = previousResult;
    result.setResult( false );

    if ( foldername != null ) {
      String realFoldername = getRealFoldername();
      FileObject folderObject = null;
      try {
        folderObject = KettleVFS.getFileObject( realFoldername, this );

        if ( folderObject.exists() ) {
          boolean isFolder = false;

          // Check if it's a folder
          if ( folderObject.getType() == FileType.FOLDER ) {
            isFolder = true;
          }

          if ( isFailOfFolderExists() ) {
            // Folder exists and fail flag is on.
            result.setResult( false );
            if ( isFolder ) {
              logError( "Folder [" + realFoldername + "] exists, failing." );
            } else {
              logError( "File [" + realFoldername + "] exists, failing." );
            }
          } else {
            // Folder already exists, no reason to try to create it
            result.setResult( true );
            if ( log.isDetailed() ) {
              logDetailed( "Folder [" + realFoldername + "] already exists, not recreating." );
            }
          }

        } else {
          // No Folder yet, create an empty Folder.
          folderObject.createFolder();
          if ( log.isDetailed() ) {
            logDetailed( "Folder [" + realFoldername + "] created!" );
          }
          result.setResult( true );
        }
      } catch ( Exception e ) {
        logError( "Could not create Folder [" + realFoldername + "]", e );
        result.setResult( false );
        result.setNrErrors( 1 );
      } finally {
        if ( folderObject != null ) {
          try {
            folderObject.close();
            folderObject = null;
          } catch ( IOException ex ) { /* Ignore */
          }
        }
      }
    } else {
      logError( "No Foldername is defined." );
    }

    return result;
  }

  public boolean evaluates() {
    return true;
  }

  public boolean isFailOfFolderExists() {
    return failOfFolderExists;
  }

  public void setFailOfFolderExists( boolean failIfFolderExists ) {
    this.failOfFolderExists = failIfFolderExists;
  }

  public static void main( String[] args ) {
    List<CheckResultInterface> remarks = new ArrayList<CheckResultInterface>();
    new JobEntryCreateFile().check( remarks, null, new Variables(), null, null );
    System.out.printf( "Remarks: %s\n", remarks );
  }

  public void check( List<CheckResultInterface> remarks, JobMeta jobMeta, VariableSpace space,
    Repository repository, IMetaStore metaStore ) {
    ValidatorContext ctx = new ValidatorContext();
    putVariableSpace( ctx, getVariables() );
    putValidators( ctx, notNullValidator(), fileDoesNotExistValidator() );
    andValidator().validate( this, "filename", remarks, ctx );
  }
}
```

May be the first solution is the best and the less invasive. But i havent had success till now. Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

did you tried to launch this scheduled job from a carte server instance?

the proper way to setup scheduled jobs or transformations remotely is to add a start step to the job (first step), click and setup the scheduling, after that, start a carte.sh server from console, setup a slave server back from you job in kettle and launch remotely, now the carte server will keep this job and the schedule.

Comment: I've never used carte server yet, so i don't really know how it works. But the problem is that i have to use my scheduler. I have to do it for various reasons. So if using carte server could solve my problem i can try it. But the little knowledge of this instrument tells me that it's not a solution. I mean, can i use carte server just to launch the job without using the scheduling feature ? And if yes, could it solve my problem ?

Comment: ok, if you have to use your own scheduler carte is not your problem solver